# Python List scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a txt file containing professors', names, ids, where they work, and titles, separated by a comma. I only want to get the names and discard the rest. Is it possible?

for example:

```
12717, PROFESÖR, ABDULLAH ERYAVUZ, AFYON KOCATEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ/VETERİNER FAKÜLTESİ/VETERİNER HEKİMLİĞİ TEMEL BİLİMLERİ BÖLÜMÜ/VETERİNERLİK FİZYOLOJİSİ ANABİLİM DALI/, Sağlık Bilimleri Temel Alanı, Veterinerlik Fizyolojisi, 1E246277D3E01142
106459, PROFESÖR, ABDULLAH KESKİN, AFYON KOCATEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ/İKTİSADİ VE İDARİ BİLİMLER FAKÜLTESİ/İKTİSAT BÖLÜMÜ/İKTİSAT TEORİSİ ANABİLİM DALI/, Sosyal-Beşeri ve İdari Bilimler Temel Alanı, Makro İktisat, Gelişme Ekonomisi - Makro ; Büyüme ; Para-Banka, akeskin[at]aku.edu.tr, C771324515A1023A
53410, PROFESÖR, ABDURRAHMAN KARABULUT, AFYON KOCATEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ/TEKNOLOJİ FAKÜLTESİ/MAKİNE MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ/MAKİNE MÜHENDİSLİĞİ ANABİLİM DALI/, Mühendislik Temel Alanı, Makine Mühendisliği, Makine Teorisi ve Dinamiği ; Makine Tasarımı ve Makine Elemanları ; Mekanik Titretişimler ve Gürültü, akarabulut[at]aku.edu.tr, C4DEB0A8828D1E78
57393, PROFESÖR, ABDURRAHMAN FATİH FİDAN, AFYON KOCATEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ/VETERİNER FAKÜLTESİ/VETERİNER HEKİMLİĞİ TEMEL BİLİMLERİ BÖLÜMÜ/VETERİNERLİK BİYOKİMYASI ANABİLİM DALI/, Sağlık Bilimleri Temel Alanı, Veterinerlik Biyokimyası, ffidan[at]aku.edu.tr, FB9466184DC835D3
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? What particular problem you are not able to solve? Check [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for item in file:
        print(item.split(',')[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

As You said, you have a txt file containing professors info. 1st we opened that txt file. then getting every lines from txt file as list. then we used a for loop to fetch every item from that list. then we use if condition to ignore blank lines. the `continue` used in for and while loop to bypass current loop and continue next one. then we converting that data into list separated with a comma and a space and storing that into a variable. the name is in 3rd index of the list, but in programming language, number starts from 0. so it will be index no 2. and lastly printing that name
Try this code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file: # Opening File
    lines=file.readlines() # Getting data from per lines
    for data in lines: # Getting Name from that data
        if data=='\n':
            continue # if any lines are empty, ignore them
        name=data.split(', ')[2] # Converting that data into list (Every info separated with a comma and space ", ")
        print(name) # Printing that Name
    file.close()
```

The Output:

```
ABDULLAH ERYAVUZ
ABDULLAH KESKÄ°N
ABDURRAHMAN KARABULUT
ABDURRAHMAN FATÄ°H FÄ°DAN
```